# Combine 2 content types into view

Tags: views

I am facing trouble with view having 2 content type without relationship.

content type 1: (toys) title, body, series_taxomony, price

content type 2: (areas) title, area_name, percentage

I'd like to have a view to display a form like
series_taxonomy and area_name are exposed to user select from list and show detail

1. serias_taxonomy
2. price
3. area_name
4. percentage

In order to complete view, what should i do and is there any way to restructure content type to do easier

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's the problem that you're having?  If you have a `Content: Type` filter, checkmark toys and areas. Then just add those 1.2.3.4. fields as filters and check mark expose filter.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I am getting you right, for this issue you should do this; 
Create a new view, and in filters option select type "toys" and again select type "areas", this will give you 2 content types into one view.

For exposed filters, in the filter criteria, select both the fields, "series_taxonomy" and "area_name" and select them as exposed filter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Following your guide and now I have 2 rows like that r1: name percentage  null null and r2: null null serials_taxonomy price. How to combine 2 rows into one?